# How to mock @injected object at parent class

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am having one @Inject object which i need to mock its throwing NPE while using @InjectMocks at my test class

Below is the structure of my class

```
Class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{

public myMethod(){

String myval=callParentClassMethod();

}

Class ParentClass{

@Inject
private MyService myservice;
//there is no constructor or setter method for this injected object

protected String callParentClassMethod(){
retrun myservice.getStringval();
}

}
```

Can you please suggest how to mock this MyService object.I have used @Mock and @Injected mock but its not working getting NPE. i tried to inject in both Base class and parent class but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

following works for me:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private ChildClass childClass = new ChildClass();

    @Mock
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        childClass.myMethod();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**
I've uploaded example project with test to https://github.com/shurick-k/mock-test

You've not specified exactly what type of @Inject annotation is used, so I assumed it is from javaee-api. Actually it does not matter.

Comment: Thanks Shurick for replying. I am still getting NPE while calling Injected Service.Is there any other way

Comment: @DhrumilShah Have you got the solution?